# How to highlight username in html table with JavaScript(almost there)

Tags: javascript

I am using the following JavaScript code to highlight one name in a html table.  Using the mark tag with a background colour to highlight the name. It works to highlight the name but breaks the format of the table and just displays a long list of text along with the correct name highlighted.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  let input = "Sally Jones";
  if (input !== "") {
    let regExp = new RegExp(input, 'gi')
    table.innerHTML = table.textContent.replace(regExp, "<mark>$&</mark>");

  }
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="sLeague-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pos</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Branch</th>
      <th>Units</th>
      <th>Profit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Roger Smith</td>
      <td>Ripon</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>£13,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Charles Strange</td>
      <td>Ely</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>£11,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Sally Jones</td>
      <td>Bangor</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>£10,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Carol Smythe</td>
      <td>Chichester</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>£9,849</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Any Beatty</td>
      <td>Exeter</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£9,175</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Jill Smithson</td>
      <td>Stevenage</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£8,964</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Peter Cousins</td>
      <td>Derby</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£7,834</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Andrea Peterson</td>
      <td>Leicester</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>£7,320</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Jon Wales</td>
      <td>Rochdale</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>£5,940</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>James Cameron</td>
      <td>Grantham</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>£5,480</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Well your code is fetching **all** of the content of the table as plain text, replacing the string, and then using the text as the new content of the table. It sounds like the browser is doing exactly what you asked it to do. Instead, maybe find the `<td>` element that has the content to be updated and just update that element instead of the whole table.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer will use this to learn more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are overriding your HTML content with the `innerContent`, which produces:

```
<table id="myTable" class="sLeague-table">
      Pos
      Name
      Branch
      Units
      Profit
    
  
  
    
      1
      Roger Smith
      Ripon
      12
      £13,000
    
    
      2
      Charles Strange
      Ely
      12
      £11,500
    
    
      3
      <mark>Sally Jones</mark>
      Bangor
      11
      £10,450
    
    
      4
      Carol Smythe
      Chichester
      10
      £9,849
    
    
      5
      Any Beatty
      Exeter
      8
      £9,175
    
    
      6
      Jill Smithson
      Stevenage
      8
      £8,964
    
    
      7
      Peter Cousins
      Derby
      8
      £7,834
    
    
      8
      Andrea Peterson
      Leicester
      7
      £7,320
    
    
      9
      Jon Wales
      Rochdale
      6
      £5,940
    
    
      10
      James Cameron
      Grantham
      5
      £5,480
</table>
```

What you might need is to replace your text inside the `innerHTML`:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () => {
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  let input = "Sally Jones";
  if (input !== "") {
    let regExp = new RegExp(input, 'gi')
    table.innerHTML = table.innerHTML.replace(regExp, "<mark>$&</mark>");

  }
});
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="sLeague-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pos</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Branch</th>
      <th>Units</th>
      <th>Profit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Roger Smith</td>
      <td>Ripon</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>£13,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Charles Strange</td>
      <td>Ely</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>£11,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Sally Jones</td>
      <td>Bangor</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>£10,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Carol Smythe</td>
      <td>Chichester</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>£9,849</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Any Beatty</td>
      <td>Exeter</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£9,175</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Jill Smithson</td>
      <td>Stevenage</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£8,964</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Peter Cousins</td>
      <td>Derby</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£7,834</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Andrea Peterson</td>
      <td>Leicester</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>£7,320</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Jon Wales</td>
      <td>Rochdale</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>£5,940</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>James Cameron</td>
      <td>Grantham</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>£5,480</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

---

One other approach is to only select `<td>` elements loop over them and insert the `<mark>` tag if their content matches your search query

Comment: Thanks! I will look at the other option also to help me better understand it.

Answer (score 2):

You're picking up the *text* content of the whole table but applying that to the table's innerHTML so you lose all the formatting.

1. Use [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) to get an array-like list of cell elements.
2. Because we'll be using [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) in this example we need to coerce this array-like structure to a proper array so you can access all its array methods. Here I've used: `[...cells]` (using the [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax), but you could also use [`Array.from`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from).
3. Use `find` to find the first cell that has the text content that matches the input value. `find` is useful because the iteration short-cuts when it finds the first match rather than continue the iteration til the end of the array.
4. Change that cell's innerHTML to the input value [wrapped in a `<mark>` element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```js
const cells = document.querySelectorAll('table td');
const input = 'Sally Jones';

const cell = [...cells].find(cell => {
  return cell.textContent === input;
});

cell.innerHTML = `<mark>${input}</mark>`;
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="sLeague-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pos</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Branch</th>
      <th>Units</th>
      <th>Profit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Roger Smith</td>
      <td>Ripon</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>£13,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Charles Strange</td>
      <td>Ely</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>£11,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Sally Jones</td>
      <td>Bangor</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>£10,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Carol Smythe</td>
      <td>Chichester</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>£9,849</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Any Beatty</td>
      <td>Exeter</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£9,175</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Jill Smithson</td>
      <td>Stevenage</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£8,964</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Peter Cousins</td>
      <td>Derby</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£7,834</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Andrea Peterson</td>
      <td>Leicester</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>£7,320</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Jon Wales</td>
      <td>Rochdale</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>£5,940</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>James Cameron</td>
      <td>Grantham</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>£5,480</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit of a different approach using CSS background-color to define a class, then simply locate the table data element whose textContent is equal to your string, if found add the class if not remove it.

```js
function highlightInfo(str) {
  table = document.getElementById("myTable");
  let targetData = table.querySelectorAll('td');
  targetData.forEach(td => td.textContent === str ? td.classList.add('highlighted') : td.classList.remove('highlighted'))
}

highlightInfo('Sally Jones');
```

```css
.highlighted {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="sLeague-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pos</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Branch</th>
      <th>Units</th>
      <th>Profit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Roger Smith</td>
      <td>Ripon</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>£13,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Charles Strange</td>
      <td>Ely</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>£11,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Sally Jones</td>
      <td>Bangor</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>£10,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Carol Smythe</td>
      <td>Chichester</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>£9,849</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Any Beatty</td>
      <td>Exeter</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£9,175</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Jill Smithson</td>
      <td>Stevenage</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£8,964</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Peter Cousins</td>
      <td>Derby</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£7,834</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Andrea Peterson</td>
      <td>Leicester</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>£7,320</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Jon Wales</td>
      <td>Rochdale</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>£5,940</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>James Cameron</td>
      <td>Grantham</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>£5,480</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for another great option, much cleaner than my original attempt, thanks

Comment: @dales landry, Working with your code I tried to adapt it to to highlight the whole row rather than just the td. After doing some research I came up with this:  if (targetData[i].value){
        targetData[i].parentNode.classList.add("highlighted");
      }
  } but its not working any ideas?

Comment: `targetData.forEach( td => td.textContent === str ? td.parentNode.classList.add('highlighted') : null )`, simply add `.parentNode` to your td element, though if your looking to remove the highlighted row if you change the query, then you may need to refactor the code a bit. Where is your name coming from exactly? You may consider using event.target if it comes from a submission of some kind.

Comment: Thanks that works perfectly for me as the name will be coming from a php variable from the login system. Funnily enough I came across the parentNode in another post and was wondering how to implement it when you answered my question. Thanks your help is much appreciated.

Comment: NP happy coding my friend

Answer (score 1):

What you're actually doing here, this line to be exact `table.innerHTML = table.textContent.replace(regExp, "<mark>$&</mark>")`, is that you're replacing the `HTML` markup of the table itself which will obviously mess things up as you have stated in your question.

You goal can be achieved in an ease way, we need to grab all the names that are `"Sally Jones"` and highlight them by replacing the `HTML` markup only on the `td`s hat do have the text needed so that each matched `td` element's `HTML` becomes something similar to `<td><mark>Sally Jones</mark></td>`.

To do so, we could optimize things by only looking at the `td`s that represent the `name column` and to only look for the text inside of those elements only. Then we can use our regex to check whether the wanted text exists or not and apply the highlighting if we have a match:

- Select all the `name` columns (the `td`s that represent the `name` column in our table) using the [`querySelectorAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) method.
- Loop through those elements
- Check if we have a matching text
- If yes, apply the highlighting

Here's a quick demo to illustrate:

```js
table = document.getElementById("myTable");
const input = "Sally Jones",
  regExp = new RegExp(input, 'gi');
/** the selector passed to "querySelectorAll" method selects only the "td"s that represent a "name" in the table */
document.querySelectorAll('td:nth-child(2)')
  /** loop through thoise "td"s and apply the highlighting if needed (if we have a matching text) */
  .forEach(td => regExp.test(td.textContent) && (td.innerHTML = td.textContent.replace(regExp, "<mark>$&</mark>")));
```

```html
<table id="myTable" class="sLeague-table">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Pos</th>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Branch</th>
      <th>Units</th>
      <th>Profit</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Roger Smith</td>
      <td>Ripon</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>£13,000</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Charles Strange</td>
      <td>Ely</td>
      <td>12</td>
      <td>£11,500</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Sally Jones</td>
      <td>Bangor</td>
      <td>11</td>
      <td>£10,450</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Carol Smythe</td>
      <td>Chichester</td>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>£9,849</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>Any Beatty</td>
      <td>Exeter</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£9,175</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>Jill Smithson</td>
      <td>Stevenage</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£8,964</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>Peter Cousins</td>
      <td>Derby</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>£7,834</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>Andrea Peterson</td>
      <td>Leicester</td>
      <td>7</td>
      <td>£7,320</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>9</td>
      <td>Jon Wales</td>
      <td>Rochdale</td>
      <td>6</td>
      <td>£5,940</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>10</td>
      <td>James Cameron</td>
      <td>Grantham</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>£5,480</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for a great explanation and a more efficient alternative to my attempt